# 是 in using 好像／像

Tags: grammar

I am really confused in regards to how 是 is used in 好像／像 sentences and sometimes not used.

For example, I can come up with something like 那朵云好像是一朵棉花。 (that cloud looks like cotton.) Can I omit 是 here?

In another case, I can compose a sentence such as 我想像 David Beckham 踢得太好 
 (I want to play soccer as well as David Beckham) and 是 is not used here.

Can somebody help me understand usages of 好像／像 and how 是 is used and sometimes not used in those sentences?

Comment: users note, in each of 像是一朵棉花, 想像 there is only one verb 是 in 1st case, 想 in 2nd

Comment: So, you use 是 when there's no verb involved? Such as the first case? Also not in the second case because there's already a verb 踢？

Comment: I might be wrong here, but the '好像是' in '那朵云好像是一朵棉花' for me means 'seems to be' not 'looks like'...

Comment: @Fai91 What's the difference between "seems to be" and "looks like" ?

Comment: 1st example NP+像是+NP (NP noun phrase,do not omit 是 )
2nd 像+NP+V+得＋adj/adv see grammars, Making comparisons 象
 bkrs:好像是,像是 1)相似。
如：「这些人造花做得像是真花一般。」(it) looks like, it is likely,大概,好像是,看来,也许，好像是你对，it looks as if you are right,2) 彷佛。
如：「听他的口气像是已经下定决心了。」as if  iciba: look like； seem；  This is more like a downpayment, or a deposit, if you like.这更像是首付，也可以说是定金。(there are more examples)  好像是 can be "I am afraid so",
像 (2)v. resemble; be like; take after; similar; alike,(4) 模拟 [imitate](5) 仿效 [follow the example of](6) 依随, 顺遂 [comply with]
像了他意, 再无妒忌。 --《古今小说》 also search site for previous disc

Comment: ＂像 David Beckham 踢得太好＂ does not appear of the standard types of comparison with 像,  像David Beckham踢球那么好，一样／一般好 (also with 跟 instead of 像）（comments #1,5  based on assumption the phrase actually occurred in the literature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 那朵云好像是一朵棉花。
>   **好像** adv. seem; as if; as though
>   **是** verb. is
>
> 那朵云好像一朵棉花。
>   **好像** verb. seems to be... ; looks like...
>   It is actually the combination of 好(quite; pretty much) and 像(seems to be).

是 here is a verb in your sentence, but we can omit 是 because 好像 can also be a verb. And the meaning is almost the same no matter whether there is 是.

> 我想像 David Beckham 踢得太好。(Actually, we don't say like this.)
>   **想** verb. want to; intend to; would like to; hope to.
>   **像** preposition. resemble; such as

However, this sentence has some problem when you want to express "I want to play soccer as well as David Beckham." 太好 here would give a negative meaning like "play too good to ... (avoid some training wound/be out of spare time/take care of family...)". The situation you can use 太好 is in exclamatory sentence:

> 他踢球踢得太好了！

So I suggest to say:

> 我想像大卫•贝克汉姆踢得那么好。  play ... so good as ...
>   or
>   我想踢得像大卫•贝克汉姆一样好。  play ... as good as ...

Comment: Can I also say 我想像大卫·贝克汉姆一样足球踢得那么好？

Comment: Also, when using 像, is 一样 replaceable?

Comment: Yes, you may say that. 那朵云像棉花 = 那朵云像棉花一样

Answer (score 0):

When 是 is used in 好像／像, meaning look like, similar to or as, you can omit 是, when  好像／像 means likely, seemingly, probably, you can not.